# IOS CUSTOM KEYBOARD CURSOR MOVEMENT

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, custom-keyboard, ios-extensions

is it possible to control the cursor movement through custom keyboard

I have two traverse buttons on keyboard on clicking them cursor moves in the respective direction.

Is it possible to implement ?

Please guide !

Comment: no is not possible to handle

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is completely possible if i understand correctly. You just need increment or reduct the offset value of the UITextDocumentProxy method.

```
- (void)adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:(NSInteger)offset;
```

e.g.

```
-(void) incrementButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
        [self.textDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:1];
}
```